# What is the root of a Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently purchased a commercial library to use in a Visual Studio (2013) project.  For commercial distribution they said that their license file should be placed in the "root" folder of the Visual Studio Project and set to be an embedded resource.

Which folder of a Visual Studio project is its "root" folder?
I've made a simplified text diagram of my project here -  branch nodes are to the bottom...

```
               MyProj (folder)

Source (folder)   Build (folder)   Documentation (folder)  
     \
      \
ProjName(folder)  Projname.sln   Projname.suo
        \
         \
bin (folder)   obj (folder)   foo1.cs  MainWindow.xml ...other source...
     \
      \
   debug(folder)
       \
        \
      MyProj.exe   ...etc...
```

Comment: You know when you create a brand new project? And it throws that Class1.cs BS into it? That class is in the root folder.  Root means lowermost.

Comment: That confuses me because in Linux root is the topmost directory, i.e., farthest from the branches.   But I don't understand your answer at all because the .cs files, i.e., the source files, are in the middle with stuff both above and below them.  Below the source folder are bin and obj folders, and the source folder is itself just one folder in a set of project folders that also include one called Build and one called Documentation all under a folder with the project name.

Comment: This is really simple https://i.stack.imgur.com/smjvN.png Imagine we're in Australia and the tree is upside down.  Also, there is never more than one root, while there may be many branches at any given level.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't relate your image to my project or understand what you are calling root or what your reference to Australia is.    Are you saying that root is where the source files are?   Since that's neither the upper-most nor lower-most node in the tree why would it be considered the root?

Comment: I've added a text diagram of my project to my question.

Comment: Look at the image.  There is a file called IAmInTheRoot.cs.  That file ***is in the root of the project***.  If you can't understand that, I'm really sorry, I can't help you.  If this is a language barrier problem, I'd suggest you ask someone else who can read English to see if they understand it better.  Good luck.

Comment: I speak perfect English, but the picture you sent is from Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, not from Windows Explorer.  So it shows a project tree not a file-system tree.   And even in your picture the IAmInTheRoot.cs file is neither at the leaf end of the tree structure (because there are other structures farther from the trunk) nor the top end so it would be a very strange use of 'root'.    Can anyone document that Visual Studio uses that as their idea of root?  In a normal file system the 'root' is the node farthest from the leaves, just like in a real tree.

Comment: Same directory that contains the project file of the project, where ever that might be in the ascii art.  VS doesn't care where you put it, nor do we.